# I want to run the application in background of mobile without any GUI in mobile using J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am developing the network application in which I want to run my J2ME MIDP application in background without any GUI so that is any way to construct the application is such manner.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't confuse (Android) Java with J2ME?

Comment: Please, specify are you talking Android or J2ME or both? I think talking both in the same question breaks the rule of one question per post. I can see you're getting both J2ME and Android answers at the same time, that's confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

set your current Display to null. so there will not be any form or alert running on the screen.  But however your code will be running in the background.

```
Display display = Display.getDisplay(this);  // here 'this' points to Midlet

display.setCurrent(null);
```

Comment: it easy just have a code of line on any event for example in the click of button

Comment: what do you mean ? I did not get you. you have Java ME Application or Android Application ?

Answer (score 1):

it easy just have a code of line on any event for example in the click of button

`Display.getDisplay (this).setCurrent (null);`

and return back the control via

`Display.getDisplay (this).setCurrent (mycanvas);`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this code works Good,

```
display = Display.getDisplay(this);
public void startApp()
{
    display.setCurrent(form);
}
public void pauseApp()
{

}
public void hide()
{
    Display.getDisplay (this).setCurrent (null);
}
```

This is will work like, make a button can after clicking it call hide Function, or you call this hide function in constructor so it will hide itself when app start, can you keep unHide statement in `appStart()` so if you Tab the program then it will unHide app again.

*NOTE: you said you are working on Network app, but some mobile will turn off the Internet Connection, when the Mobile screen Turn Off. please check this. and If you found any solution It will be Good to share here.*